# How can I record audio AMR format?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, microphone, amr

I am creating a Windwows Phone 7 application which needs that audio from the microphone should be stored in AMR format.

I'm able to catch MemoryStream from microphone, but how can I save that stream with AMR codec?

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid no available amr encode lib you can use directly.

it seems impossible to translate c lib to wp7 edtion.

if you want to compress data ,you can study the wav format . Reduce the audio sampling rate can compress data too.